# tsql format as percentage

Tags: t-sql

I have the following sql statement:

```
SELECT 1, 2, 3

UNION ALL

SELECT CAST(1 AS VARCHAR) + '%',CAST(2 AS VARCHAR) + '%',CAST(3 AS VARCHAR) + '%'
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1%' to data type int.
```

I could change the first select statement to '1','2','3', but i have a many unions and only one row that has to have the percentage format.  Is there any other alternatives that are available?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you want to mix data like this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
select cast(1 as varchar) ,cast(2 as varchar), cast(3 as varchar)

union all

select cast(1 as varchar) + '%',cast(2 as varchar) + '%',cast(3 as varchar) + '%'
```

Reason of error is you above select having 1,2,3 which is an integer values and you are doing union with the varchar value

so solution is you need to convert you above select data type to varchar

The second solution is

```
Select cast(col1 as varchar),cast(col2 as varchar),........... from
(
   .. all your union large query you have writting
) d

union all
select cast(1 as varchar) + '%',cast(2 as varchar) + '%',cast(3 as varchar) + '%'
```

Comment: Thanks Pranay, i was actually after an alternative to doing this, I have a large query with a heap of unions, so I don't want to change all the unions for just one percentage row.

Comment: @campo - you write on sub query and do the thing I am giving you one alternative

Comment: ah ok, i only saw your original answer without the alternative, not the edited version that you added to.  thanks

Comment: Thanks, the 2nd solution was perfect for what i needed!

Answer (score 2):

You **need** to CAST all union clauses.

Every row in the final output with have the [highest precedence datatype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx). `int` is higher than `varchar`, so `1%` is cast to int with obvious results

```
select cast(1 as varchar), cast(2 as varchar), cast(3 as varchar)
union all
select cast(1 as varchar) + '%',cast(2 as varchar) + '%',cast(3 as varchar) + '%'
```

Or: you can not have a different datatypes/formats in one column.

Of course this is an example, but mixing ints and formatted floats makes no sense even if SQL did allow it

Comment: +1 Thanks for explaining the highest precedence datatype, I didn't know how SQL server was determining the data type for the column.